# Can't get picture veritcally centered in a div

Tags: html, css

Yet again, I can't get an image to center inside a specific div. The answers I've come across only center it horizontally, but not vertically

```css
#wrap { 
width: auto; 
margin: 0 auto; 
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
}
/*header info if needed
#headerBlock { 
height: 200px; 
background:  #776b68; 
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

div.headerText {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 90px;
}

div.headerImg {
display: inline-block;
}
*/ 

#leftBlock { 
width: 50%; 
height: 500px; 
background: #000; 
float: left; 
}

#leftBlock img {
display: block;
margin: auto;
transition: transform 4s;
}

#leftBlock img:hover {
transform: scale(1.8);
}

#rightBlock { 
width: 50%; 
height: 500px; 
background: #8ab78f; 
float: left; 
}

#rightBlock img {
display: block;
margin: auto;
}

/*ignore footer*/
#footerBlock { 
height: 200px; 
background:  #29342a ; 
clear: left; 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="headerBlock">
    <div class="headerText">blah blah blah so neat</div>
    <div class="headerImg"><img src="/yupyup.jpg" height="70" width="70">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="leftBlock">
    <img src="/leftside.jpg" height="250" width="250">
</div>

<div id="rightBlock"></div>
     <img src="/rightside.jpg" height="250" width="250">
<div id="footerBlock"></div>

</div>
```

The issue I'm coming across is, it only likes to center it horizontally. The only solution i found was doing the following below, but all that's really doing is moving it all over the screen and me having to pin point where it goes (which should be inside that leftBlock div..) :

```
#leftBlock img {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 305px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -450px;
transition: transform 4s;
}
```

Comment: `img` should be inside `rightblock div`. But looks like it is outside. correct the typo

Comment: @Siva you're right - fixed that part! Although the image centering is still a problem

Comment: Please create a simplified example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: A simple example would help a lot in jsfiddle or somewhere would be helpful

Comment: did you use `vertical-align: middle` in css??

Comment: @AsifSharifShahid I did try that, couldn't get it to go vertically.

Comment: @Huangism sorry new to this site. Is this better?

https://jsfiddle.net/gxg3c2mp/

Comment: @Brandon you can not use `float` property with `vertical-align`, floating is not a good approach for this you have to use bootstrap grid system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the end goal, you want to add `position: relative` to the parent, remove the margins on the image and use `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` combined with `top: 50%; left: 50%` to center the image relative to the parent.

```css
#wrap {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}


/*header info if needed
#headerBlock { 
height: 200px; 
background:  #776b68; 
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

div.headerText {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 90px;
}

div.headerImg {
display: inline-block;
}
*/

#leftBlock {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #000;
  float: left;
}

#leftBlock img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: transform 4s;
}

#leftBlock img:hover {
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1.8);
}

#rightBlock {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #8ab78f;
  float: left;
}

#rightBlock img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}


/*ignore footer*/

#footerBlock {
  height: 200px;
  background: #29342a;
  clear: left;
}

#leftBlock {
  position: relative;
}

#leftBlock img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transition: transform 4s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="headerBlock">
    <div class="headerText">blah blah blah so neat</div>
    <div class="headerImg"><img src="/yupyup.jpg" height="70" width="70">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="leftBlock">
    <img src="/leftside.jpg" height="250" width="250">
</div>

<div id="rightBlock"></div>
     <img src="/rightside.jpg" height="250" width="250">
<div id="footerBlock"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: This kind of works. So it's centering it correctly now. But it's not doing it without the use of that `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` part. The transform i had in there was to hover and scale the picture. This seems to be bringing the picture down.

Comment: @Brandon ah sorry about that, missed the other transform in your code. You can apply multiple transforms by putting a space between the values. Updated my answer - that work like you expect it?

Comment: ah perfect! That's what i needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have a simple solution for you! make your body and html height 100%. also add height to the relevant div in which you want to make it vertical center and use this code below. its verified.

```css
body,html{ height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

.display-table-container {
  display: table;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto
}

.display-cell-container {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative
}
```

```html
<div class="display-table-container">

<div class="display-cell-container">Insert your image here</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example that I put together that I hope helps you out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background: yellow;">
    <div style="background: black; height: 200px; width: 
       200px;position: relative;top: 50%; left: 50%;transform: 
       translate(-50%,-50%);">
       this is a div yo
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So basically just do `position: relative;top: 50%; left: 50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);"` on what you want to be centered inside

Comment: is there an alternative to the `transform:translate` part? This works but the on hover to scale the image messes it up.

Comment: the alternative would be to use percentages for the inside div like: `height: 30%; width: 30%;position: relative;top: 35%; left: 35%;"`

Comment: `<div style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background: yellow;">
    <div style="background: black; height: 30%; width: 
       30%;position: relative;top: 35%; left: 35%;">
       this is a div yo
    </div>`